# Do we need php framework to setup facebook php-sdk 4.x.x

Tags: frameworks, facebook-php-sdk

I have tried setting up php-sdk on one of my domains but it throws server error 500 I am not sure whether it is because of php or it requires me to have a framework on my web host.

Comment: The PHP SDK v4 does not require a specific web framework in order to use it. But it requires PHP 5.4 or greater. What version of PHP are you using? Also - if you turn errors on, that will give you a better idea of what's going on other than a generic 500 message.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, later on I assumed that my php code was incomplete which was the reason for this error. Can you help me with publishing Custom stories on facebook, if I pay a couple of $ ?

Comment: If you have a specific issue using the SDK, I'd love to point you in the right direction, but I'm not available to create an app at the moment. :)

Comment: Just need a little guidance to clear my doubts that's it. Can you gimme an email where I can get in touch with you ?

Comment: You can reach me using my [contact form](https://www.sammyk.me/contact) if you like. :)